# Ruby: instance_exec with a block taking a block as parameter

Tags: ruby

Please consider the following code:

```
def a &block_a
    define_method :b do |&block_b|
        puts "Running in define_method"
        instance_exec block_a, &block_b
    end
end

a do
    puts "In block A"
end

b do |&block|
    puts "In block B"
    instance_eval &block
end
```

I'd like the block given to method 'b' to be given as argument the block given to method 'a' (b being created dynamically).
However the following output/error is returned:

```
Running in define_method
In block B
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..3)
(repl):14:in `instance_eval'
(repl):14:in `block in <main>'
(repl):4:in `instance_exec'
(repl):4:in `block in a'
(repl):12:in `<main>'
```

It seems like the '&block' is nil (trying to call 'block.call' instead of 'instance_eval &block' raises 'block is nil' error). The logic seems to be good since the replacing the 'b' block argument with a string does work:

```
def a s
    define_method :b do |&block_b|
        puts "Running in define_method"
        instance_exec s, &block_b
    end
end

a "LOL"

b do |s|
    puts "In block B"
    puts s
end
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incredibly hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish and I am 102% positive you are overcomplicating things (read: doing it wrong.)

The issue with your code is you are lost in blocks and their parameters.

For `block` in `b` method call to be not `nil`, `b` should `yield` something to it, and yielding blocks is not permitted. Instead of yielding, one might explicitly call the block:

```
def a &block_a
  define_method :b do |&block_b|
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
    block_b.(&block_a)
  end
end

a { puts "A" }

b { |&block| puts "B"; instance_eval &block }
```

other way round might be to accept a normal parameter in `b`, since what you pass there is `block_a`, which is a normal `proc` instance:

```
def a &block_a
  define_method :b do |&block_b|
    instance_exec block_a, &block_b
  end
end

a { puts "A" }

#   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
b { |block| puts "B"; instance_eval &block }
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like I got messed up with the '&' syntax :). Actually this code will run in a class and define methods for it so I think I need the 'instance_eval' solution.

Comment: It seems like every Ruby question I've looked at today has an answer from you with a √ next to it.